# 400 - bad request - request is syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, http

this is my code

```
var myObj = 
{
   "id": 0,
   "createdDate": "12-12-2014 12:00:00",
   "fromEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
   "sampleBooleanValue": false,
   "extraDescrition":"ssfsvgsf",
   "sampleArraay":[{"arrayElem1"}, {"arrayElem2"}]
};

console.log(downtime1);

$rootScope.httpPost('createMyObj/', myObj).success(function (successdata) {
    console.log(successdata);
}).error(function (errordata) {
    console.log(errordata);
});
```

I have my REST endpoint created with URI createMyObj but as soon As I hit submit I get 400-bead request - the request submitted is syntactically incorrect error.

Is my JSON in correct format?

EDIT:
Here is my corrosponding Java bean

`public class MyObj {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String fonEmail;
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> sampleArraay;
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate;
    private Boolean sampleBooleanValue;
    private String extraDescription;`

Comment: Have you tried checking your backend with a program like Postman?

Comment: I dont have much backend than just a REST api. My method reateMyObj in java just return true right now without any further process on the received object.

Comment: Why would you ever make `$http` a property of `$rootScope`? Doesn't make sense to pollute it when dependency injecting a  service is no more complex than injecting `$rootScope`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array from the sampleArraay field is invalid. Try:

```
var myObj = {
  "id": 0,
  "createdDate": "12-12-2014 12:00:00",
  "fromEmail": "abc@gmail.com",
  "sampleBooleanValue": false,
  "extraDescrition":"ssfsvgsf",
  "sampleArraay":["arrayElem1", "arrayElem2"]
};

console.log(downtime1);
$rootScope.httpPost('createMyObj/', myObj).success(function (successdata) {
  console.log(successdata);
})
.error(function (errordata) {
  console.log(errordata);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"sampleArraay":[{"arrayElem1"}, {"arrayElem2"}]

Looks to be wrong. Were you planning for the elements of sampleArraay to be nested objects?

Also at the risk of being flippant, the spelling in your example, words like "Array" and "Description" are wrong. Could it be a case of being spelled wrong in one place and not in the other?

One thing I like to do when I get 400 errors like this is progressively simplify the object I am trying to send by commenting out elements until I get to the culprit.

I did this on JSFiddle.com (a great resource) with your code and a simple alert statement to confirm the array problem.